# Grafana user variables

Tags: mysql, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

is it possible to use Grafana's userID or user variables in MySQL query ?

For example :

```
SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE user_id=$Grafana.User.id
```

Or is there another way to assign a custom variable to specific user within Grafana ?

Comment: what's your question  .. you have error ?? show th error message ..

Comment: I'm trying to pass in Grafana's user ID to the query. Is there a variable that can give me loggedin user ID from Grafana

Answer (score 4):

It is available in Grafana 7.1+ as `${__user.id}`. Check the doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/
This should work:

`SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE user_id=${__user.id}`